# snmp shared tables after reconnect to master agent

Tags: snmp

I am using agentx++ to create shared tables.
After a snmpd restart, the subagent reconnects to the master agent but all rows in the shared tables are deleted.
Any Idea why the rows are deleted upon snmpd restart?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of mechanism do you have for saving the data to DB? All row data may be kept in RAM during agent lifetime...